# API Gateway Returns HTTP 413 For GET Requests With No Body

Tags: aws-api-gateway

My application is receiving an HTTP 413 "Request Entity Too Large" response from AWS API Gateway when sending a `GET` request to *download* a file.

While the requested file is > 29 MB in size, that is returned in the *response*, of course.  As I understand it, an HTTP 413 pertains to the body of a *request*.

Why would API Gateway be returning an HTTP 413 if there is no body in the request?

Below are details from a `curl` command of the same URL my application uses.

```
curl -v  https://api-gateway-host.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/file
*   Trying <IP address>:443...
* Connected to api-gateway-host.us-east-1.amazonaws.com (<IP address>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Aug 24 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 22 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api-gateway-host" matched cert's "*.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7f8fed80d400)
> GET /path/to/file HTTP/2
> Host: api-gateway-host.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
> user-agent: curl/7.77.0
> accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 413 
< date: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 21:43:06 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 38
< apigw-requestid: arw4qjGbIAMEMugqerq=
< vary: Origin
< vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host api-gateway-host.us-east-1.amazonaws.com left intact
{"message":"Request Entity Too Large"}
```

Also, this same application, located in a different environment (QA), can make these same kinds of requests for the same file successfully.

The config has only one stage (`$default`), the route (`ANY /path/{proxy+}`)integrates with an ALB, and has no authorizations.

I have reviewed the API Gateway configurations of the two environments, but cannot find any differences.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, did you ever get to the bottom of this?  Thanks!

Comment: @Nik I believe we discovered the error IS referring to the size of the response.